# imageView selected state doesn't show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my application I have one activity (HomeActivity) and 3 fragments (So I have 3 buttons). In HomeActivity I have buttons that should changed his state after clicking on it. When first run application I press one of this button selected state changed (in my case white to green) but when I press another button all buttons come to unselected  (all buttons is white). Could anyone tell me what is the problem in here?

```
public class HomeActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mMessageButton;
    private ImageView mMapButton;
    private ImageView mSettingsButton;
    private int mCurrentFragmentId = DISCOUNT;
    public List<ImageView> mPageItems;
    public int mSelectedPage = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        init();
    }
    private void init(){      
        mMessageButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.message_icon);
        mMapButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.map_icon);
        mSettingsButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.settings_icon);
    mPageItems = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        mPageItems.add(mMessageButton);
        mPageItems.add(mMapButton);
        mPageItems.add(mSettingsButton);

        mMessageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mMapButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void addPage(final DefaultHeaderFragment pDefaultFragment, final boolean isAddToBackStack){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mPageItems.get(mSelectedPage).setSelected(true);
        transaction.replace(R.id.f_pager, pDefaultFragment);
        if (isAddToBackStack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.message_icon:
                mSelectedPage = 0;
                MessagesFragment messagesFragment = new MessagesFragment(HomeActivity.this);
                Bundle messageArgument = new Bundle();
                messageArgument.putInt("fragmentId", mCurrentFragmentId);
                messagesFragment.setArguments(messageArgument);
                addPage(messagesFragment, true);
                break;
            case R.id.map_icon:
                mSelectedPage = 1;
                YandexMapFragment mapFragment = new YandexMapFragment(HomeActivity.this);
                Bundle mapArgument = new Bundle();
                mapArgument.putInt("fragmentId", mCurrentFragmentId);
                mapFragment.setArguments(mapArgument);
                addPage(mapFragment, true);  
                break;
            case R.id.settings_icon:
                mSelectedPage = 2;
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment(HomeActivity.this);
                Bundle settingsArgument = new Bundle();
                settingsArgument.putInt("fragmentId", mCurrentFragmentId);
                settingsFragment.setArguments(settingsArgument);
                addPage(settingsFragment, true);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/map_icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_margin_between_icons"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/button_indicator_message_button"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@id/map_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/settings_icon"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_margin_between_icons"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/button_indicator_map_button"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@id/settings_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/header_marginLeft_marginRight"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/button_indicator_settings_button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id = "@+id/f_pager"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

button_indicator_message_button

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/message_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/message_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/message_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 7):

inside the `onClick` you should call `view.setSelected(true);` in order to force the content of the `ImageView` to change